# DataContractSerializer config section under System.Runtime.Serialization section group could not be loaded

Tags: .net

> DataContractSerializer config section under System.Runtime.Serialization section group could not be loaded. Verify that machine.config is correctly set up.

Do I need to reinstall something?

Comment: i have .net framework 3.5 sp1 installed

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this issue? I have the same problem on clients PC while installing my software.

Comment: I have this problem, but only in windows 8.1

Answer (score 1):

Data contract serializer goes under behaviour or servicebehaviour
http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms731809.aspx

Comment: Sorry, but how should this help? I have the same problem.